# fill missing value based on quarter

Tags: python, pandas

let us  suppose we have following  information about georgia country

```
georgia =pd.read_excel("https://geostat.ge/media/52173/ganawileba-sacxovrebeli-adgilis-mixedviT.xls",skiprows=[0])
georgia.head()
```

result is :

[image]

as you see  there is missing informations about years, but we can see that  given year is divided into quarters, therefore  logical will be  fill  missed data with corresponding year grouped by quarter right ? for instance if we try :

```
georgia.groupby('კვარტალი')['წელი'].head()
```

which stands show year(წელი) for each quarter(კვარტალი)
result would be :

```
0     2014.0
1        NaN
2        NaN
3     2015.0
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7     2016.0
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
11    2017.0
12       NaN
13       NaN
14       NaN
15    2018.0
16       NaN
17       NaN
18       NaN
19    2019.0
Name: წელი, dtype:
```

float64
how  can  i extract  use given information for filling missed value? i think it should be super easy but i can't guess and please give hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
georgia['წელი'] = georgia['წელი'].ffill()
georgia.groupby('კვარტალი')['წელი'].head()
```